# How to query multiple combinations in a sql query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I would like to write a query, for e.g.

```
Select * From dbo.[dataset]

Where _date BETWEEN '2022-..-..' AND '2022-..-..'
--first condition
AND Animal = 'Dog' AND Dog_Colour = 'Beige'
--Second condition
AND Animal = 'Cat' AND Cat_Colour = 'Black'
--next condition..
AND etc...
```

I'd like to pull a combination of animals and colours together, only when the conditions are met for each line. Can someone help please?

Comment: Looks as you need OR between your condition combinations

Comment: please only tag with your actual database

Comment: Based on the use of the `dbo` (schema) I have **assumed** SQL Server here; if this is not correct you need to [edit] your question to correct your tags.

Comment: You can group expressions that need to be evaluated together using parentheses `()`. You can also use an `OR` clause where needed as well. Example: `WHERE (expression1 AND expression2) OR (expression3 AND expression4)`

Comment: Instead please OR

Comment: ( ) OR ( ) OR ( ) OR ETCC

Answer (score 1):

An SQL OR condition should be good enough for the query.

```
Select * 
From dbo.[dataset]
Where _date BETWEEN '2022-..-..' AND '2022-..-..'
AND 
(
  --first condition
  (Animal = 'Dog' AND Dog_Colour = 'Beige')
  --Second condition
  OR (Animal = 'Cat' AND Cat_Colour = 'Black')
  --next condition..
  OR ( Animal = 'XXX' AND XXX_Colour = 'YYY' )
)
```